# JPA disable schema creation for single entity

Tags: jpa

I have a `@Entity` for a MySQL view in a JPA/Hibernate project. During development, I'm using 
`javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=drop-and-create` to quickly reset my database. This should ignore the above view, it will be created later in the initialization script.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack to solve this (and the frequent dropping problems during `drop-and-create`) is as follows:

1. Drop and recreate the database
2. Make JPA create the schema (including wrongly creating the view as a table)
3. Drop the view's table in the data loading script and create the view instead.

Config:

```
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source", "script-then-metadata");
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source",
    env.getRequiredProperty("script.root") + "/project/scripts/before-autocreate.sql");
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source",
    env.getRequiredProperty("script.root") + "/project/scripts/init.sql");
```

before-autocreate.sql:

```
drop database if exists xxx;
create database xxx;
use xxx;
```

start of init.sql:

```
drop table if exists lastinventory;
drop view if exists lastinventory;
create view lastinventory as ...
```